# Passing value of dropdown to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to pass the selected value of dropdown to my link, so that when i call my link its corresponding action should function as per the id selected from dropdown. In alert the value is coming but now how would i pass this value to param1 of link.
**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var BASE_PATH = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>";
 function changeSelectedVal(val){
   var center_id = val;
   /* document.getElementById('centerid').val();*/
   alert("Selected id = "+center_id);
   }
 </script>

<div>
<?php
  echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'center_id', 
  CHtml::listData(Center::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                array('empty' => '--Select Center--',
                    'onchange'=>'changeSelectedVal(this.value)',
                )); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">    
        <?php    
       echo CHtml::link('Generate PDF', array('country/printCenter', 'param1'=>'center_id'));
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the current output of `echo CHtml::link('Generate PDF', array('country/printCenter', 'param1'=>'center_id'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_PATH = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>";

    function changeSelectedVal(val){

        var url = '<?php echo $this->createUrl("country/printCenter"); ?>&param1='+ val;
        $('#mylink').prop('href',url);


    }
</script>

<div>
<?php

        echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'center_id',  CHtml::listData(Center::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
            array('empty' => '--Select Center--',
                'onchange'=>'changeSelectedVal(this.value)',
            )); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">

    <?php

   echo CHtml::link('Generate PDF', array('country/printCenter', 'param1'=>'center_id'), array('id'=>'mylink'));
?>
</div>
```